# $S_n \in [-a,a]$ for some $a$ infinitely often

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Suppose we have iid r.v.s $X_n \in \mathbb{R}$ with mean $0$ variance $\sigma^2$, I wonder is it true that we have $\exists a>0,$ 
$$P(S_n \in [-a,a] \text{ infinitely often} )=1,$$

where $S_n =\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. In the case of integer valued $X_n$, the above is true by strong law of large numbers and Kesten-Spitzer-Whitman theorem.

By Hewitt–Savage $0-1$ law, we know the above probability is $0$ or $1$. But it looks hard to me to determine if it is positive or not.

Comment: What is $S_n$? $$\qquad $$

Comment: Yes, it is true. You can find a detailed proof in Theorem 9.1 and 9.2 of *Foundations of Modern Probability (2e)* by Olav Kallenberg.